# FLVPlayback won't seek when streaming from flash media server. How to fix?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, flvplayback, flash-media-server

I have a simple video player set up that streams from a flash media server. The video plays fine, but the majority of the seek commands send it back to the first frame of the video. If I don't use flash media server it will seek to any point which has already been loaded.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was checking the FLVPlayback playing property to see if I wanted to call play after the seek (The video didn't auto-play, and I wanted it to play if you seeked). The playing property however is set to false after a seek call till it is done seeking apparently. This resulted in play being called every time, which reset the playhead to the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try and download jw player from here http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ and test if it works with that player. The problem could lay with the streaming server.

> the majority of the seek commands send
>   it back to the first frame

What happens with the rest? - Do they work or does nothing happen?

Comment: Rarely it seeks properly, most of the time it fails and goes back to the start.

I just tried the same video with the player that comes with the flash media server and it works fine. Obviously something is wrong with my controls or flvplayback. Are there any settings that I might be missing?